# How to retrieve power bi audit logs through REST API

Tags: office365, powerbi

Power BI Audit Logs are saved up to 90 days. I would like to have it historically and I would like to extract them on a daily basis through REST API. 
So I created an app under my active directory, and I granted rights for office 365 management API. 
Is that the right choice or I should choose Microsoft Graph? 
I see that under office 365 management API, audit logs should be under the content type Audit.General.
Information that I would like to see is which user did what under our workspaces.

schema:

- Id
- RecordType
- CreationTime
- OrganizationId
- Workload
- UserId
- UserAgent
- Activity
- ItemName
- WorkspaceName
- DashboardName
- Datasets